# Creating a Groovy Portlet

Tags: json, rest, groovy, portlet, portal

I am getting started researching / creating a groovy portlet that will connect to a REST based ESB service that returns JSON; I will also need to pass the username in the headers. I was wondering if there are any examples out there on how to create the portlet and set the headers? I am new to groovy and from what I understand this can be accomplished rather easily. Essentially I want a portlet that will allow a user to search for a widget via a search box and return a list of matches. Not sure that it matters but the portlet will be deployed to the Vignette Portal. Any info would be much appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a portlet with Java/Groovy is very doable with Spring Portlet MVC.  I used some sample code from various sources a year ago but googling on it will give you more modern examples and let you pick something more applicable to your app.  The real issue comes up with how you plan on building your app.  Gradle is the best option for writing a Groovy web app.

However if you are talking about using Grails, then it becomes much more difficult and I would not advise learning Grails as you are trying to get it jammed into a 'portal' implementation.  There are plugins for Liferay and 'portlets' in Grails but when I last looked at them earlier this year, they did not seem fully baked.

Calling REST based services with JSON or whatever from your server code doesn't have to care that you are in a 'portal'.  The big issues comes up when you are trying to create the UI with your portal provider specific APIs.  Don't be fooled into thinking you won't be using portal specific stuff.  We used Liferay a bit and from my perspective the Portlet spec was very slim so to do much of anything interesting in a portal, you have to use some portal specific stuff, at least for UI and authentication services.

So my suggestion is build a Gradle Groovy Web project and use the Spring Portlet MVC Java examples to get something going and then you can simplify with Groovy as it makes sense.  Initially you might want to simply start with Java if that is your comfort zone because integrating with your portal might be daunting enough without trying to learn a new language to boot.